# Prove or Disprove $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin(nx) $ converge uniformly to $x$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I want to prove $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin(nx) $ converges pointwise and uniformly to $x$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  I know $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converge by alternating series test. And $\sum a_n \sin(nx)$ converge by Dirichlet test if $a_n$ is decreasing sequence. But in this case this does not work. Maybe it just we can just consider the interval without $-\pi$,$\pi$. I get lost. Please help. Thanks a lot
After trying, I think maybe there is no uniform convergence?

Comment: The proof in Fourier Analysis is quite elementary. It uses the simple  idea of 'summation by parts'.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. Would you mind pointing me to the right book?or would you illustrate it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The book by Edwards on Fourier series has  a section called 'The series  (C) and (S)  as Fourier series'. There is nice discussion of series of the type $\sum a_n \sin (nx)$ and $\sum a_n \cos (nx)$.

Comment: Well it may converge point-wise and uniformly, but in which interval ?

Comment: @Siddhartha I don't know for sure. Does (-pi,pi) work? Please guide me

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes there is this section but I do not understand the pages. Maybe I do not have enough knowledge.

Comment: On [mathoverflow.se]: [Disprove $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin(nx) $ converge uniformly to $x$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ using elementary analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/q/358850).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convergence is not uniform on $(-\pi,\pi)$ (although it is on compact subintervals).

To prove non-uniform convergence note that

$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin nx }{n} = -2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos n\pi \frac{\sin nx }{n} = -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n(\pi+x) }{n} $$

However, taking $x_n = -\pi + \frac{\pi}{4n} \in (-\pi,\pi)$ we have for $n < k \leqslant 2n$ that $\frac{\pi}{4} < k (\pi+x_n) \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$ which implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < \sin k (\pi+x_n) \leqslant 1$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\sup_{x \in (-\pi,\pi)}\left| \sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{\sin k(\pi+x) }{k}  \right|\geqslant  \sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{\sin k(\pi+x_n) }{k}  > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot n \cdot \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

The LHS fails to converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ and the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence is violated.

$$$$

Comment: Nicely done!  I hope that you're doing well my friend.

Comment: The OP originally asked to show UC.  Since the, the question was edited.  So, I've added a new section with an alternative proof to yours.  I'd be grateful if you would have a look whenever you have a moment.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> **NOTE:  The original question that the OP asked was**
>
> "Prove $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin(nx) $ converge pointwise and uniformly to $x$ on $[0,2\pi]$ using elementary analysis"**

---

Let $a_n(x)=(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)$ and $b_n(x)=\frac1n$.  Obviously, $b_n(x)\to 0$ monotonically and uniformly as $n\to\infty$.

Moreover, for any $0<\delta_1<\pi$ and $0<\delta_2<\pi$, and $x\in [-\pi+\delta_1,\pi-\delta_2]$,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n(x)\right|&=\left|\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)\right|\\\\
&\le\left|\sec(x/2)\right|\\\\
&\le \max(\csc(\delta_1),\csc(\delta_2))
\end{align}$$

Therefore, [Dirichlet's Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence#Theorem) guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[-\pi+\delta_1,\pi-\delta_2]$.

---

**EDITED: After the OP changed the question**

We now give a proof that the series $2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{n}$ fails to converge uniformly for $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$.

We first note that the series converges to $-x$ for $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$.  That is to say that the Fourier series for $x$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ is given by

$$x=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{n}$$

Now let $f_N(x)$ be the $N$th partial sum of the Fourier series for $x$.  Then, denoting $t=x+\pi$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
f_N(x)&=2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{n}\\\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(nt)}{n}\\\\
&=-2\int_0^t \sum_{n=1}^N \cos(nu)\,du\\\\
&=t-\int_0^t \frac{\sin((N+1/2)u)}{\sin(u/2)}\,du\\\\
&=t-\int_0^{(N+1/2)t}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{x/(2N+1)}{\sin(x/(2N+1))}\,dx
\end{align}$$

It suffices to show that $\int_0^t \frac{\sin((N+1/2)u)}{\sin(u/2)}\,du$ fails to converge uniformly to $\frac\pi2$ for $t\in (0,2\pi)$.  Now take $t=1/(N+1/2)$

Then, we see that

$$\sin(1)\le\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{x/(2N+1)}{\sin(x/(2N+1))}\,dx\le \csc(1)$$

Hence we conclude that the convergence of $f_N(x)$ fails to converge uniformly on $(-\pi,\pi)$.  And we are done!

Comment: Could you explain more about the two inequality sign? Thank you so much

Comment: @user123469123131 The sum $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)$ can be evaluated in closed form from which the bound is easily seen.  In the second, the secant function $\sec(x/2)$ is a maximum at $x=\pi-\delta$.

Comment: do you proof hold when I replace 0 in the proof by $-\pi$?Cuz I want to prove uniform convergence on $(-pi,pi)$ now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ Mark Viola Is you proof still correct when I replace 0 in the proof by $-\pi$?Cuz I want to prove uniform convergence on $(-\pi,\pi)$ now. Please examine my edit to see if it is OK.Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes.  For any $\delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2>0$, the convergence is uniform on $[-\pi+\delta_1,\pi-\delta_2]$.

Comment: You changed the nature of your question after I submitted a valid answer to the original question.  That is in bad form.

Comment: I am sorry for that. Anyway thanks for your contribution. I appreciate your effort and kindness.

Comment: I've edited to add the proof of the failure of UC on $(-\pi,\pi)$.